# Cross partition query is required but disabled

Tags: asp.net

This happens when I'm writing this code

```
       List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {

            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
        }

        return results;
```

[image: HERE WHAT HAPPENING]

T

Comment: How do you create `query`? It seems you forgot to add `var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };` to your query.

Comment: While this may be triggered by the code that you showed, the error messages indicate that this is really due more to some details of your database setup (maybe try enabling cross partition queries, per the error message). Please include more information about your setup.